# Pentaho Data Integration Community Edition 9.4 - Shared objects file feature of transformation doesn't support variable

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

Our company used Pentaho Data Integration Community Edition (PDI-CE) 8.0 (Linux). We are upgrading to the PDI-CE 9.4. In the process, we met an issue.

To reproduce the issue, clone the project https://github.com/albertwangnz/reproduce-shared-objects-file-issue-pdice-9.4.

When we used PDI-CE 8.0, we used the feature `Shared objects file` in the transformation Miscellaneous tab. We defined database connections in different files to support different database engines. We set up a variable `DB_CONN_SHARED_FILE` in a previous transformation step. The value of the variable is the location of a shared object file (XML), like `sharefiles/database-connections-mysql.xml`. Then we used the variable as the value of the Shared objects file field as shown below. So, we could dynamically support various database engines, like MySQL, SQL Server, with the same `*.ktr` files.

[image]

It used to work in PDI-CE 8.0. But after we upgraded to PDI-CE 9.4, it does not work anymore. If we hard-code the value in the Shared objects file field, as shown below, like `sharefiles/database-connections-mysql.xml`, it works. But the variable does not work anymore.

[image]

I wonder if anyone met the same problem and knows how to fix it.

Thank you.

Regards,
Albert

- The version of PDI-CE is 9.4.0.0-343
  ** The version of Linux is Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS